# Fastest Algorithm for finding All Pairs Shortest Paths on Sparse Non-Negative Graph

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, shortest-path, sparse-matrices, dijkstras-algorithm

As discussed [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7644/what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-finding-all-shortest-paths-in-a-sparse-graph) Johnson's Algorithm can be used to solve the APSP-Problem in $O(V^2\log V + VE)$ in stead of $O(V^3)$ for Floyd-Warshall. However, Johnsons Algorithm does quite a bit of work for the case that some weights are negative. Is there a faster way to compute this given that all weights are positive?